# Applying SPARQL filter returns no results, why?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to find abstracts for every wikiPageWikiLink of a given set of resources. When I add the FILTER condition to filter only english abstracts, I get no results. Why?

```
SELECT ?resource ?snippet
WHERE
{ 
VALUES ?item { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/National_Basketball_Association> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Addiction> }
?item <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource .
?resource <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?snippet 
FILTER(LANG(?snippet) = "en")
}
```

[With Filter](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fresource%20%3Fsnippet%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0AVALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNational_Basketball_Association%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAddiction%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%3Fitem%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageWikiLink%3E%20%3Fresource%20.%0D%0A%3Fresource%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fabstract%3E%20%3Fsnippet%20%0D%0AFILTER%28LANG%28%3Fsnippet%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)
[Without Filter](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fresource%20%3Fsnippet%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0AVALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNational_Basketball_Association%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAddiction%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%3Fitem%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageWikiLink%3E%20%3Fresource%20.%0D%0A%3Fresource%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fabstract%3E%20%3Fsnippet%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)

I'm using [this form](https://dbpedia.org/sparql) to create.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your results directly in your answer as text or using the built in image formatting. Otherwise your question will not stand on its own. Especially since these links appear to be broken.

Comment: This is more an issue with the query optimizer of the Virtuoso backend. Virtuoso itself has some anytime feature, i.e. it returns whatever it find in a given time period. Default is 30s in the web interface, you could increase the value of course. But the main point here is, the query isn't really complex. It just looks like the `VALUES` is used rather late. You can see how fast it should be when you set of the items directly

Comment: it returns the result instantly: `SELECT ?resource ?snippet
WHERE
{ 

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/National_Basketball_Association>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource .
?resource <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?snippet 
FILTER(LANG(?snippet) = "en")
}`

Comment: you can try to use a `FILTER IN` instead (although `VALUES` would be the intended way to provide inline data ...): `SELECT ?resource ?snippet
WHERE
{ 
?item <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource .
FILTER (?item IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/National_Basketball_Association>, <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Addiction>))
?resource <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?snippet 
FILTER(LANG(?snippet) = "en")
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Uninformeduser, this works way faster!

```
SELECT ?resource ?snippet WHERE {  ?item <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> ?resource . FILTER (?item IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/National_Basketball_Association>, <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Addiction>)) ?resource <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?snippet  FILTER(LANG(?snippet) = "en") }
```